# java string array sort

Tags: java, sorting

I have to sort list of arrays by date. I did not known how to do it, so i have added all values into one value. This is almost work fine, but it do not sort years good This is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        String s1 ="2016|07|21 15:26:20!947!-0.0091002";
        String s2 ="2015|08|21 15:26:20!977!0.0091002";
        String s3 ="2015|07|22 15:26:20!947!1.0091002";
        String s4 ="2015|07|21 16:26:20!946!0.0091001";
        String s5 ="2015|07|21 15:27:20!977!0.0091002";
        String s6 ="2015|07|21 15:26:21!947!1.0091002";
        String s7 ="2015|07|21 15:26:20!946!0.0091001";
        ar.add(s1);
        ar.add(s2);
        ar.add(s3);
        ar.add(s4);
        ar.add(s5);
        ar.add(s6);
        ar.add(s7);
        Collections.sort(ar.subList(1, ar.size()));
        Object[][] data = {
                {ar.get(0)},
                {ar.get(1)},
                {ar.get(2)},
                {ar.get(3)},
                {ar.get(4)},
                {ar.get(5)},
                {ar.get(6)},
        };
```

and this is output:

```
2016|07|21 15:26:20!947!-0.0091002
2015|07|21 15:26:20!946!0.0091001
2015|07|21 15:26:21!947!1.0091002
2015|07|21 15:27:20!977!0.0091002
2015|07|21 16:26:20!946!0.0091001
2015|07|22 15:26:20!947!1.0091002
2015|08|21 15:26:20!977!0.0091002
```

but this is what I need:

```
2015|07|21 15:26:20!946!0.0091001
2015|07|21 15:26:21!947!1.0091002
2015|07|21 15:27:20!977!0.0091002
2015|07|21 16:26:20!946!0.0091001
2015|07|22 15:26:20!947!1.0091002
2015|08|21 15:26:20!977!0.0091002
2016|07|21 15:26:20!947!-0.0091002
```

And i've got no ida why is this happend

Comment: Collection.sort(ar.sabList(0, ar size()); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
Collections.sort(ar);
```

to sort the entire list.

Remember that Java lists are zero-based, so `ar.get(0)` is the first element. `List.subList(i, j)` returns the sublist from `i` (inclusively) to `j` (exclusively).

So, to sort the whole list via a sublist, you'd need to use `i = 0` and `j = ar.size()`. However, the indirection of the sublist is unnecessary: just pass the list itself to `Collections.sort`.

Comment: a little off topic, it's necessary to convert those strings to date and sort them as date using a custom Comparator? or is better to keep them as strings?

Comment: Depends on what you're going to do with them once they're sorted. If you're just printing them out, it makes no difference. If you're doing something else for which you need them as dates, keep them as dates. Since `Date` implements `Comparable<Date>`, so you don't need a custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's wrong with your code

```
    Collections.sort(ar.subList(1, ar.size()));
```

You are trying to sort indices 1~N, so index 0 is not sorted.

What you should be doing is sort the entire `ArrayList` like this

```
    Collections.sort(ar);
```

This will sort the `ArrayList<String>` in ascending order.

**Output**

```
2015|07|21 15:26:20!946!0.0091001
2015|07|21 15:26:21!947!1.0091002
2015|07|21 15:27:20!977!0.0091002
2015|07|21 16:26:20!946!0.0091001
2015|07|22 15:26:20!947!1.0091002
2015|08|21 15:26:20!977!0.0091002
2016|07|21 15:26:20!947!-0.0091002
```

However, your code just sorts the string list in ascending order so if you have month/date/year in different order, it will not be sorted by time. You should be using Date/Time utils available in Java or other libraries like Apache.

Answer (score -1):

You are sorting only a view of a sublist of your list, which will have no effect on the list you actually want to return. Indeed, `List.sublist` returns a **new** list.

By the way, your code could be much shorter :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
    "2016|07|21 15:26:20!947!-0.0091002", "2015|08|21 15:26:20!977!0.0091002", "2015|07|22 15:26:20!947!1.0091002",
    "2015|07|21 16:26:20!946!0.0091001", "2015|07|21 15:27:20!977!0.0091002", "2015|07|21 15:26:21!947!1.0091002", "2015|07|21 15:26:20!946!0.0091001");
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: Untrue. Sorting a sublist (of `ArrayList`, at least) causes the original list to be updated.

Comment: @AndyTurner oh, right, it is not a new list. However, I've looked at the doc and saw that only non-structural modifications were reflected. There is also this : `Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results`. Isn't a sort concerned by the second case ?

Comment: what iterations are in progress?

Comment: You mean in the OP's code ? That's not the question, this is a definition, not something you apply to a particular case. I'm not positive that a sort is a structural modification, but it does not look absurd to me seeing this definition

Comment: If I would like to add all vaues in one place, I would use 'String[] ar = {...}'

Comment: @anat In practice you almost never use arrays in a Java code, because they provide a too light API and do not allow things like immutability, abstraction and so on. Most of the times, you will end up using arraylists

Comment: @anat Also, you cannot reasonably argue that your code is better without `Arrays.asList`, so you should just use it and make it more readable.